# How to refer to one table when two tables have been used in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

Up until now I have just been using one table in a MySQL query, but now I am using two tables in a query to return only users' favourites, i.e.:

```
$query1="SELECT tracks.id, favourites.track FROM tracks, favourites WHERE tracks.id = favourites.track";
$result=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

I am wondering how then I would refer to columns in rows in just the tracks table to construct variables from this query.  Previously I used:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$title = $row['title'];
...etc
}
```

But obviously this needs adapting to refer to just the rows in the tracks table, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same using:

```
$query1="SELECT T.id as Tid, F.track , T.title as Title FROM tracks T inner join favourites F ON T.id = F.track";
 $result = mysql_query($query1);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
 {
     $title = $row->Title;
     $tid = $row->Tid;
     /*...etc...*/
 }
```